# How to turn a dataframe into vectors with column name as names

Tags: r, dataframe

Say I have a dataframe `df` with columns 'Height', 'Weight',...

I want these columns to be variables so I can use Height by just calling Height and not have to type df$Height. What is the function to do this to every column in a dataframe?

Comment: It is not recommended.  But you can do `attach(df)`

Comment: why is it not recommended?

Comment: because it creates lots of objects in the global env unncessarily

Comment: Depending on what you want to do with the data, `dplyr` and other `tidyverse` packages are designed for manipulation of data frame columns by name.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do this, but this is a rare situation.

```
# See the column names in mtcars
names(mtcars)
# [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"

# Use a for loop to loop through columns in mtcars with assign
for (i in 1:ncol(mtcars)){
  assign(names(mtcars)[[i]], mtcars[[i]])
}

# Call the column mpg
mpg
# [1] 21.0 21.0 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 17.8 16.4 17.3 15.2 10.4 10.4 14.7 32.4
# [19] 30.4 33.9 21.5 15.5 15.2 13.3 19.2 27.3 26.0 30.4 15.8 19.7 15.0 21.4
```